# request for member '' in something not a structure of union

Tags: c, struct, compare

sorry for writing a new question because it gies other questions that are the same but I can not find out what is wrong here :( can anybody help.

My code is

```
typedef struct First_s
{
    double a;
    double b, c;
    double d;
} First_t;

typedef struct Second_s
{
    char e[10];
    long f;        
    First_t g; 
} Second_t;

int compare(Second_t *x, Second_t *y)
{
    if(x.g.b >y.g.b){
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me an Error:

> request for member 'g' in something not a structure of union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a Pointer to a struct. To retrieve the contents of a pointer you need to dereference it first (and check if its not `NULL`):

```
int compare(Second_t *x, Second_t *y)
{
    if(x->g.b >y->g.b){
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I wanted to give a +1 but my reputation is way below 15 :(

Answer (score 4):

You're using `.` when you should use `->` to access the structure fields.

Since  `x` and `y` are pointers, you cannot access them directly with `.` unless you first dereference with the asterisk (`*`) operator, i.e. `(*x).g.b` works. Nobody does that though, the typical way is to use the `->` operator since that's what it's there for.

Also, a `compare()` function should never *modify* its arguments, so they should be constant pointers:

```
int compare(const Second_t *x, const Second_t *y)
{
  /* code here */
}
```

Comment: thank you, I wanted to give a +1 but my reputation is way below 15 :(